# Error in adding Checked Changed Event to a checkbox- which is added dynamically to a gridview in asp.net application using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

This is my code

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    dataReader.Read();
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "chkbox";
        if (int.Parse(dataReader[0].ToString()) == 0)
            cb.Checked = false;
        else
            cb.Checked = true;
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkBoxChange);
        row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(cb);
    }
}
```

But even though I had written:

```
cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkBoxChange);
```

the function

```
public void chkBoxChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                   
}
```

is not invoking when I checked the CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

### [ Tested Code ]

You can use below code in `OnRowCreated` and `OnRowDataBound` events of GridView.

This way will successfully invoke the `CheckedChanged` event of dynamically created CheckBox.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    CheckBox cb = e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox;
    if (cb == null)
    {
        cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "chkbox";
        cb.AutoPostBack = true;
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkBoxChange);
        e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(cb);
    }
}
```